# opencv on M1 wheel built from source results in "is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Tags: macos, opencv, python-wheel, python

I tried to build opencv-python from source since there is no wheel yet for my Apple M1 laptop.
that runs numpy 1.20.1, pip 21.0.1 python 3.9.1

So after cloning the git and altering the pyproject.toml to support numpy 1.20.1 and python 3.9.1 the wheel was built using

> python -m pip wheel .

resulting in

> opencv_python-4.5.1.48-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_2_arm64.whl
> which looks correct from the tags

however when installing it using

> python -m pip install opencv_python-4.5.1.48-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_2_arm64.whl

> ERROR: opencv_python-4.5.1.48-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_2_arm64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

how is that possible when it was build on the same system a minute ago. Does anyone have an idea?

could the problem be that python -vv tells me that I have a clang version?

> Python 3.9.1 (default, Feb 18 2021, 23:17:57) [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)]

I could not find any other question where the wheel was build from source on the same machine.